# define belongsToMany relation with self referencing table in sequelize

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

i have "User" table with phoneNumber as a table column.

I want to have association so that each User can add many contacts... basically contacts will be other User.

Usually in many to many relation we have two tables and a joining table.
But can i have one table, that is User table and a joining table referencing to User itself ??

my User table:

```
const User = sequelize.define(
    "users",
      phone_number: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      } );
```

can i have following "UserContact" joining table without "Contact table" with this association

```
User.associate = (models) => {
    models.User.belongsToMany(models.Contact, {through: 'UserContact' })
  };
```

my UserContact table:

```
const UserContact = sequelize.define(
    "user_contacts",
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      contact_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    }
  );
```

Is there any other way like referencing contacts through some field in User table itself?? again one user should have one or many contacts.

Comment: Yes, you can create such table that references the same table multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate `User` model in a association and indicate fields for both sides:

```
User.associate = (models) => {
    models.User.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'UserContact' }, foreignKey: 'user_id', otherKey: 'contact_id')
  };
```